# Aidl error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, aidl

Execution failed for task ':devsmartAndroid:compileReleaseAidl':

> org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/inheritx/Android_SDK_NEW/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.1.0/aidl''

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to SDK manager
2. Click Launch Standalone Manager
3. Make sure that you already downloaded the Android SDK Build-tools and Platform-tools under Tools(Preview Channel) 23 rc1
4. Make sure that you have download the latest Android Support Library and PlayStore services under Extras and then restart Android Studio
   The build gradle should look like:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   ```

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 'android-MNC'
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1"

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "org.code2care.myapplication1"
       minSdkVersion 'MNC'
       targetSdkVersion 'MNC'
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   ```

   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   }